# Keeping parent div to width and height of wrapping children

Tags: html, css

I am building a simple calendar. I am wanting the months to wrap responsively on screen, and the parent container to keep the width and height of its children. For example, if the screen is 950px wide and the months 100x100, I'd have 9 months on one line and three on the next, with the parent container being 900 x 200. So far I can only manage to get dimension of either 900 x 0 with the parent display set to 'inline' or 910 x 200 with the parent display set to 'inline-block'.

I hope I have explained that OK?

For what it is worth here in my code...

***EDIT***
In an attempt to clarify the problem I have added a blue background. I would like to end up with some responsive code that, regardless of the screen with, will not show any blue to the right of the right-most child (month) div.

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <style>
      .cal {position:relative; display:inline-block; border:3px solid yellow; box-sizing:border-box; background-color:blue}
      .month {float:left; width:250px; height:170px; border:3px solid red; background-color:white; box-sizing:border-box;} 
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="cal">
      <div class="month">Jan</div>
      <div class="month">Feb</div>
      <div class="month">Mar</div>
      <div class="month">Apr</div>
      <div class="month">May</div>
      <div class="month">Jun</div>
      <div class="month">Jul</div>
      <div class="month">Aug</div>
      <div class="month">Sep</div>
      <div class="month">Oct</div>
      <div class="month">Nov</div>
      <div class="month">Dec</div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen thats not happening?

Comment: I want the parent div to create a box around the child divs, without any empty space between the right hand most child and the parents right border.  At the moment the parent's width is showing at 100% regardless.

Comment: @Jules I managed to use flexbox to get a calendar with it's parent *shrinkwrapped around the content. I assumed you wanted fixed dimensions for the children divs , unfortunately, I don't think there is a viable workaround without stretching the child divs I managed only a table half of the width needed.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the parent to shrink again to fit the width of the children each time a child wraps.  I'm afraid there is no pure CSS way to do that.

Not to change your spec, but I'd suggest keeping the parent at 100% width, and stretching/shrinking the children to fit the parent.  I, of course, don't know if that's an option for you, or if the width of the children must be fixed.  If it is an option, flexbox or media queries are two good ways to go about it.  If it isn't, you'll have to resort to JavaScript.

Here's an example using media queries and `calc()`:

```css
.cal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  border:3px solid yellow;
}
.month {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% / 12);
  height:170px;
  border:3px solid red;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) { .month { width: calc(100% / 6); } }
@media (max-width: 600px) { .month { width: calc(100% / 4); } }
@media (max-width: 400px) { .month { width: calc(100% / 3); } }
```

```html
<div class="cal">
  <div class="month">Jan</div>
  <div class="month">Feb</div>
  <div class="month">Mar</div>
  <div class="month">Apr</div>
  <div class="month">May</div>
  <div class="month">Jun</div>
  <div class="month">Jul</div>
  <div class="month">Aug</div>
  <div class="month">Sep</div>
  <div class="month">Oct</div>
  <div class="month">Nov</div>
  <div class="month">Dec</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d1bn43t6/).

If you're really wanting the `.month`s to be a fixed width, here's a bit of javaScript that'll do what you want:

```
var calcWidth = function() {
    var maxCalWidth = document.body.clientWidth - 9,
        monthWidth = 77,
        monthsPerRow = parseInt(maxCalWidth / monthWidth),
        newWidth = monthsPerRow * monthWidth + 9;
    document.querySelector('.cal').style.width = newWidth + 'px';
};

calcWidth();

window.onresize = calcWidth;
```

NOTE that some numbers are hard-coded.  You probably don't want to do that, I was just being lazy without jQuery.  Here's the [**JSFiddle for that**](http://jsfiddle.net/d1bn43t6/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost perfect, just apply `box-sizing:border-box;` to `.cal` and `.month` elements. because border width is excluded from width without using  `border-box`.

I think that's not possible with css, i could find a best possible solution for your answer in my following code

```
<html>
    <head>
      <style>

      .cal {position:relative; display:inline-block; border:1px solid yellow; text-align: center;}
      .month {float:none; margin:3px -2px; width:180px; height:170px; border:2px solid red; display: inline-block;} 
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="cal">
      <div class="month">Jan</div>
      <div class="month">Feb</div>
      <div class="month">Mar</div>
      <div class="month">Apr</div>
      <div class="month">May</div>
      <div class="month">Jun</div>
      <div class="month">Jul</div>
      <div class="month">Aug</div>
      <div class="month">Sep</div>
      <div class="month">Oct</div>
      <div class="month">Nov</div>
      <div class="month">Dec</div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

We can just make it a little better looking by centering all children, because the reserved space on first line couldn't be deducted from parent's width.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't solve it I'm afraid, the parent width is still expanding to 100%

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer, that is the best possible solution i could find.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it is still not quite the effect I am looking for. I'm not sure if I have explained the problem very well initially. I have edited the question to hopefully clarify things. Maybe it is not possible of course.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.5'Palatino Linotype';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #EFE;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.shell {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5em .75em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: max-content;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  left: 0;
}
.cal {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  outline: 3px solid yellow;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: min-content;
  max-width: 900px;
  flex: 3 0 90%;
}
.month {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 170px;
  outline: 3px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="shell">
    <div class="cal content">
      <div class="month">Jan</div>
      <div class="month">Feb</div>
      <div class="month">Mar</div>
      <div class="month">Apr</div>
      <div class="month">May</div>
      <div class="month">Jun</div>
      <div class="month">Jul</div>
      <div class="month">Aug</div>
      <div class="month">Sep</div>
      <div class="month">Oct</div>
      <div class="month">Nov</div>
      <div class="month">Dec</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```